# Check whether a li element has any children with value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if the each li element has any value or not using jQuery. I am providing my code below.

```js
$("#navbarNavDropdown ul a").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('li').has("ul").length) {
    alert('Yeah, we have a ul ' + $(this).text());
  } else {
    alert('Yeah, we dont have a ul ' + $(this).text());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
            <li><a href="/vocational-school-programs/fl/jacksonville">Jacksonville</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega-drop pstatic">
      <a href="/admissions" class="mainmenuitem">Admissions<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My requirement is: suppose inside the loop 1st li element has some children(`ul`) value here I want to print the text and 2nd `li` element has no children(`ul`) so it will come under else part. If also check the `submenu(i.e-Level 2)` has any `ul` value or not. My code is not working as expected.

Comment: have you tried with contains()

Comment: yes, its showing the wrong value means showing all 4 value in else part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```js
$("#navbarNavDropdown ul li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("ul").length) {
    alert('Yeah, we have a ul ' + $(this).text());
  } else {
    alert('No, we dont have a ul ' + $(this).text());
    $(this).find('span').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
            <li><a href="/vocational-school-programs/fl/jacksonville">Jacksonville</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega-drop pstatic">
      <a href="/admissions" class="mainmenuitem">Admissions<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The parent `UL` has two child means `li` why its coming 4 times inside the same loop.

Comment: It will check for all `ul` and `li`. You expect something else?

Comment: Actually I had requirement to remove the down arraow icon(`<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>`) if that element has no value in drop down list. Thats why I was checking. Can you do this ?

Comment: Yes, I updated snippet. I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This code will work you fine.

```js
$("#navbarNavDropdown ul a").each(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('li').has("ul").length) {
    alert('Yeah, we have a ul ' + $(this).text());
  } else {
    alert('Yeah, we dont have a ul ' + $(this).text());
    $(this).find('span').remove(); //to remove the span
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
            <li><a href="/vocational-school-programs/fl/jacksonville">Jacksonville</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega-drop pstatic">
      <a href="/admissions" class="mainmenuitem">Admissions<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> But as per me, there is a better piece of code for your requirement

```js
$("#navbarNavDropdown > ul > li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).has("ul").length) {
    alert('Yeah, we have a ul ' + $(this).text());
  } else {
    alert('Yeah, we dont have a ul ' + $(this).text());
    $(this).find('span').remove(); //to remove the span
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
            <li><a href="/vocational-school-programs/fl/jacksonville">Jacksonville</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega-drop pstatic">
      <a href="/admissions" class="mainmenuitem">Admissions<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**I have changed the `#navbarNavDropdown ul a` to `#navbarNavDropdown>ul>li` so it will only loop 2 times *[saving the time and only looping first level elements removing the `span`]* and as per your comment, I think this is the code you looking for.**

I hope this solves your Bug.

Comment: I am confusing. Can you do like this if any li element has no value just remove respective span tag please ?

Comment: for removing respective span tag write `$(this).find('span').remove();` in the else section

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` elements do not have any child `<ul>` or `<li>` elements. The one `<ul>` is a sibling not a child.

If you meant it to be a child you need to change your html so that the closing `</a>` is after the closing `</ul>`. Note though since you have child `<a>` elements you won't be able to wrap the whole thing in the anchor as that is invalid html and the browser will not create such a structure.

You need to change your line to something that checks for siblings like:

```
$(this).next('ul').find('li ul').length
//Or go back up to the parent element and then go searching back down
$(this).parent().find('li ul').length
```

Answer (score 0):

ul is not inside a element, so `$(this).find('li').has("ul")` couldn't work.

use `$(this).next()` get ul element.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative.

```js
$("#navbarNavDropdown ul").each(function() {
  $.each(this.children, function(index, element) {
    const text = element.innerText.split('\n').reverse()[0];
    if (element.localName === 'li' && $(element).has('ul').length > 0) {
      alert('Yeah, we have a ul ' + text);
    } else {
      alert('Yeah, we dont have a ul ' + text);
      $(element).find('span').remove();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
            <li><a href="/vocational-school-programs/fl/jacksonville">Jacksonville</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega-drop pstatic">
      <a href="/admissions" class="mainmenuitem">Admissions<span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```